# Problems after installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed VS 2010 SP1 last week and have noticed a couple of problems.

1. My Class template disappeared. I can no longer right-click and select Add > Class... or select Add > New Item... > Class
2. ASP.NET MVC 3 will not install (Note: I installed the SP1 stand-alone version first, not the one from MS Web Platform Installer that includes MVC)

Anyone else see anything odd?

Comment: There are issues installing and uninstalled previews/betas/RCs of ASP.NET MVC 3 after VS2010 SP1 is installed. Do you have a beta release of ASP.NET MVC 3 or ASP.NET Web Pages (with Razor) installed on the machine? You can easily check this in Add/Remove Programs. If that's the state that you're in then we're working on a Knowledge Base (KB) article for the Microsoft Support site that discusses how to fix it. Feel free to email me at elipton-AT-microsoft.com for more info.

Comment: @Eilon I didn't have any previews/betas/RCs installed. I ended up uninstalling SP1 and did a repair to get my Class template back. I then tried reinstalling from the Web Platform Installer. All appeared to work fine but then noticed MVC 3 did not install, although it said it did. Found some info that said I needed to have the VS disk to get MVC up and now all is working.

Comment: I added a new answer that contains a link to the new KB article that we published: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dandax : For the first issue that you mentioned can you goto the [VS Install Path]/Common7/IDE/ItemTemplates/[CSharp/VB]/Code and Verify the Class.Zip file is present? In any case, if you think you encounter these issues consistently, then I would suggest you adding a bug to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio , where you will get the right help.

Comment: Class.zip was no longer present. I ended up adding it myself and ran devenv /setup

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published a Knowledge Base (KB) support article on the most common causes of this failure as well as solutions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531566

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleages had issues with Team Foundation Server after installing SP1.

Comment: any idea what issues your colleague had? I'm using Ultimate.

Comment: I would be interested to see What kind of issues your colleague is facing with respect to TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Since installing VS2010 SP1, Visual Studio crashes occasionally and Outlook crashes constantly when I click 'Send', 'Reply', 'Reply All', 'Forward' or 'New'.

I'm currently going through the lengthy process of uninstalling the SP (which will apparently render may VS components inoperable), uninstalling VS2010 and then just re-installing VS2010.

Very unhappy.